# mysql composite if column from composite values?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, composite

I need to add an extra column to my query results,

The column needs to be called percent,
If `col1 == 0` then `percent` should contain `NIS` else `percent` should contain `ceil(col2 / col1 * 100)`

So I believe the following should work:

`IF(col1 = 0, 'NIS', ceil(col2 / col1 * 100)) as percent`

But I run into an issue as col1 and col2 are also composite's.

```
COUNT(distinct i.id) as col1
COUNT(distinct q.id) as col2
```

So I get hit with

> Unknown column 'col1' in 'field list'

I could get around that issue with
`IF(COUNT(distinct i.id) = 0, 'NIS', ceil(COUNT(distinct q.id) / COUNT(distinct i.id) * 100)) as percent`

But that just seems like a bunch of extra processing to me, surely there is a better way around that?

### Full Query

```
SELECT 
  `t`.*,
  `r`.`name` AS region_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.ptype_id SEPARATOR "|") AS ptype_ids,
  COUNT(DISTINCT q.id) AS quoted,
  COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) AS intended,
  COUNT(DISTINCT qa.id) AS awarded,
  IF(
    intended = 0,
    `"NIS"`,
    CEIL(quoted / intended * 100)
  ) AS percent 
FROM
  (`tradesmen` t) 
  LEFT JOIN `regions` r 
    ON `r`.`id` = `t`.`region_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `quotes` q 
    ON `t`.`id` = `q`.`tradesman_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `quote_intentions` i 
    ON `t`.`id` = `i`.`tradesman_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `quotes` qa 
    ON `q`.`tradesman_id` = `qa`.`tradesman_id` 
    AND qa.accepted = 1 
  LEFT JOIN `ptypes_tradesmen` p 
    ON `p`.`tradesman_id` = `t`.`id` 
GROUP BY `t`.`id` 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: You say "*extra processing*", but I believe MySQL will only calculate the `COUNT()` functions once and cache the result for use in each reference.  Also, be aware that the data type of your resulting `percent` column will be a string even where it contains a numeric value... why not use `NULL` in place of `'NIS'`?

Comment: I think this has something to do with the order SQL statements are evaluated and that the alias is not available until later. I will be interested to see the real answer.

Comment: @eggyal That's what I was hoping as well, but either way it also looks messy, so hopefully there is a better way

Comment: Please post the full query you ran that gave the "unknown column" error.

Comment: @Hailwood: The only other way would be to use a subquery that defines `col1` and `col2`, then reference those from the outer/parent query to calculate `percent`.

Comment: @eggyal eww sub queries ;) I think I might stick with my multiple `Count`'s if it came to that!

Comment: @eggyal I guess I could use `NULLIF` for the `NIS`, If you order by (DESC) on a int column that also has null's are the nulls at the top or bottom of the list?

Comment: From [Working with `NULL` Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/working-with-null.html): "*When doing an `ORDER BY`, `NULL` values are presented first if you do `ORDER BY ... ASC` and last if you do `ORDER BY ... DESC`.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [`SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html):

> It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a `WHERE` clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the `WHERE` clause is executed. See [Section C.5.5.4, “Problems with Column Aliases”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html).

Whilst the manual doesn't explicitly say so, the same reasoning applies to referring to a column alias within a ***`select_expr`***.

You could place your query in a subquery to an outer one that calculates `percent` using the column aliases:

```
SELECT *, IF(intended, CEIL(quoted / intended * 100), NULL) AS percent FROM (
  SELECT 
    `t`.*,
    `r`.`name` AS region_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.ptype_id SEPARATOR "|") AS ptype_ids,
    COUNT(DISTINCT q.id)  AS quoted,
    COUNT(DISTINCT i.id)  AS intended,
    COUNT(DISTINCT qa.id) AS awarded
  FROM
    (`tradesmen` t) 
    LEFT JOIN `regions` r 
      ON `r`.`id` = `t`.`region_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `quotes` q 
      ON `t`.`id` = `q`.`tradesman_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `quote_intentions` i 
      ON `t`.`id` = `i`.`tradesman_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `quotes` qa 
      ON `q`.`tradesman_id` = `qa`.`tradesman_id` 
      AND qa.accepted = 1 
    LEFT JOIN `ptypes_tradesmen` p 
      ON `p`.`tradesman_id` = `t`.`id` 
  GROUP BY `t`.`id` 
  LIMIT 20
) t
```

However, I don't think this is really worthwhile as I *believe* (am looking for a reference that I can cite, but nothing forthcoming yet) MySQL will only calculate each `COUNT()` once and use the cached result in each reference.